# Error: setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build

Tags: android, json, flutter, android-studio, dart

I am currently building a weather app that gives us the information of the temperature and climate(if rainy or windy or sunny).I am using the http and geo-locator package for building my app.Using an api key and json decode i am retrieving the information.

I am getting the following error

Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:57160/pspjoes2GlI=/ws

```
Error: setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
This Overlay widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets.  A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was:
  Overlay-[LabeledGlobalKey<OverlayState>#044ff]
The widget which was currently being built when the offending call was made was:
  Builder
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:64547/dart_sdk.js:5348:11)
    at http://localhost:64547/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:29299:23
    at framework.StatefulElement.new.markNeedsBuild (http://localhost:64547/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:29307:26)
    at overlay$.OverlayState.new.setState (http://localhost:64547/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:17689:43)
    at overlay$.OverlayState.new.rearrange (http://localhost:64547/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:31894:12)
```

Here is my code

Main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:clima/screens/loading_screen.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: LoadingScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

LoadingScreen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'location_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter_spinkit/flutter_spinkit.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import'package:clima/services/weather.dart';
const APIkey = '9f2e463e61258ef5a8b9a9bd11733b62c';
class LoadingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoadingScreenState createState() => _LoadingScreenState();
}
double MyMarginAsDouble;
double latitude,longitude;
class _LoadingScreenState extends State<LoadingScreen> {
void initState(){//if i call getlocation inside init method it automatically gets the location without the need of a button
  super.initState();
  getLocationData();
}
  Future<void> getLocationData()
  async {
 WeatherModel weatherModel = WeatherModel();
 var weatherData = weatherModel.getLocationWeather();
 Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder:(context){
   return LocationScreen(
     locationWeather: weatherData,//weather data links to networkHelper cls in networking.dart gets the weather info using http package
   );
 }
 ));
  }
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body:Center(
      child:SpinKitDoubleBounce(
        color:Colors.white,
        size:100,
      )
    )
  );
}
}
```

Location_screen.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:clima/services/weather.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:clima/utilities/constants1.dart';
import 'package:clima/services/weather.dart';
WeatherModel o = WeatherModel();
class LocationScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  LocationScreen({this.locationWeather});//yow will be passed WeatherData variable (it contains the info of the weather retrieived frm the http api url) (WeatherData of the loading_Screen).
  final locationWeather;//LocationWeather receives the information
  @override
  _LocationScreenState createState() => _LocationScreenState();
}

class _LocationScreenState extends State<LocationScreen> {
  WeatherModel weather = WeatherModel();
  int temperature;
  double temp;
  String weatherIcon;
  int condition;
  String cityName;
  @override
  void initState(){

    super.initState();
    updateUi(widget.locationWeather);

}
  void updateUi(dynamic weatherData)
  {
   var condition = weatherData['weather'][0]['id'];//api contains id eg 300 for light drizzle and so on
    temp = weatherData['main']['temp'];
   temperature=temp.toInt();
   cityName = weatherData['name'];
weatherIcon =weather.getWeatherIcon(condition);//pass that condition to a method in getWeatherdata
   print(temperature);
  }
  Future<void> getLocation()
  async {
    LocationPermission permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    print(position);
  }
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('images/location_background.jpg'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                Colors.white.withOpacity(0.8), BlendMode.dstATop),
          ),
        ),
        constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      var weatherData = await weather.getLocationWeather();//we need to gaurantee that this wont return null as it will take long time to execute
                      updateUi(weatherData);
                    },
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.near_me,
                      size: 50.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.location_city,
                      size: 50.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      '$temperature°',
                      style: kTempTextStyle,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      weatherIcon ,
                      style: kConditionTextStyle,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15.0),
                child: Text(
                  "${o.getMessage(temperature)}in $cityName!",//
                  textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                  style: kMessageTextStyle,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Location.dart

import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

```
class location{
  double latitude;
  double longitude;
  Future  getCurrentLocation()
  async {
    try{
      LocationPermission permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
      Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.low); //high is battery consuming
      LocationPermission permission1 = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
      latitude=position.latitude;
      longitude=position.longitude;
    }
    catch(e)
    {
      print(e);
    }
  }

}
```

Networking.dart

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
class NetworkHelper {
  NetworkHelper(this.url);
  var url;
  Future getData() async {
    //var url = Uri.parse(url);
    //var url = Uri.parse('api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=92e463e61258ef5a8b9a9bd11733b62c');
    http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      String data = response.body;
var decodedData = jsonDecode(data);
return decodedData;
    }
    else {
      print(response.statusCode);
    }
  }
}
```

Weather.dart

```
import '../location.dart';
import 'networking.dart';

class WeatherModel {

  Future getLocationWeather()
  async {
    location ob= new location();
    await ob.getCurrentLocation();
    print(ob.latitude);
    print(ob.longitude);
    //calling networkHelper
    NetworkHelper networkHelper = NetworkHelper('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${ob.latitude}&lon=${ob.longitude}&appid=92e463e61258ef5a8b9a9bd11733b62c&units=metric');
    var WeatherData = await networkHelper.getData();
    return WeatherData;
  }

  String getWeatherIcon(int condition) {
    if (condition < 300) {
      return '';
    } else if (condition < 400) {
      return '';
    } else if (condition < 600) {
      return '☔️';
    } else if (condition < 700) {
      return '☃️';
    } else if (condition < 800) {
      return '';
    } else if (condition == 800) {
      return '☀️';
    } else if (condition <= 804) {
      return '☁️';
    } else {
      return '‍';
    }
  }

  String getMessage(int temp) {
    if (temp > 25) {
      return 'It\'s  time';
    } else if (temp > 20) {
      return 'Time for shorts and ';
    } else if (temp < 10) {
      return 'You\'ll need  and ';
    } else {
      return 'Bring a  just in case';
    }
  }
}
```

city_Screen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:clima/utilities/constants1.dart';

class CityScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CityScreenState createState() => _CityScreenState();
}

class _CityScreenState extends State<CityScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('images/city_background.jpg'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                child: FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_back_ios,
                    size: 50.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: null,
              ),
              FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text(
                  'Get Weather',
                  style: kButtonTextStyle,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Conststants1.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const kTempTextStyle = TextStyle(
  fontFamily: 'Spartan MB',
  fontSize: 100.0,
);

const kMessageTextStyle = TextStyle(
  fontFamily: 'Spartan MB',
  fontSize: 60.0,
);

const kButtonTextStyle = TextStyle(
  fontSize: 30.0,
  fontFamily: 'Spartan MB',
);

const kConditionTextStyle = TextStyle(
  fontSize: 100.0,
);
```

Comment: You are using a Future in `initState` which is not correct according to the Flutter framework. Extract that method out somewhere and then call it in the `initState`

Comment: @Hamza I have written the getLocationData method outside the init statement and called it in the init state . I didnt get what u r trying to say .Can u pls explain?.

Answer (score 1):

Change your getLocationData method like this:

```
getLocationData() async {
WeatherModel weatherModel = WeatherModel();
var weatherData = await weatherModel.getLocationWeather();
if (weatherData != null) {
  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
    return LocationScreen(
      locationWeather: weatherData,
    );
  }));
}
}
```